# Debugging AS 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging

I'm in need of some insight to debugging the following oddity that i'm experiencing. This small block of code has been working correctly for around 2 months and all of a sudden it no longer functions as expected and i don't know why as I've made no changes to it recently.

```
//Start Extract Calling Class method
//Magic Trace #1 comes much earlier in class init
trace("pathArr: "+pathArr); //<-- Magic trace #2
instance.trRoot.selMission.SaveMission(selFile,pathArr);
//End Extract Calling Class method


public function SaveMission(fileName:String=null, pathArr:Array=null):void{
    trace("pathArr: "+pathArr);
    if(pathArr != null){
        trace("pathArr: "+pathArr);
        trace("LastFP: "+pathArr[pathArr.length-1]);
        Utils._AddToVirtualFileSystem(fileName,pathArr[pathArr.length-1],"File",Utils._GetDataSize(this));
        //Create Mission, Waypoints, Populate Missions Entry WPT ID Field
        Utils._AddNewMission(this);
    }else{
      //...handle null path
    }
}

//Deep copies an array
public static function DeepCopy(source:Object):*{ 
    var myBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
    myBA.writeObject(source); 
    myBA.position = 0; 
    return(myBA.readObject()); 
}
```

The *if* statement validates that pathArr is **not** null but when the *Utils._AddToVirtualFileSystem* method is called the method triggers an exception stating that pathArr is null when passed.

All code that affects the class this block resides in is synchronous and to my knowledge it's not been changed elsewhere. The only thing i can think of is that the system is slowing down due to a complex trig/log/algebra background simulation happening for another completely encapsulated class that is cycling at 250ms an iteration.

Could this slowdown be causing the if statement to falsely evaluate?.

**Console Output - Without 2 magical traces in:**

```
pathArr: 
pathArr: 
LastFP: undefined
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at HUD.Components::TrComp/AddToVirtualFileSystem()[C:\Users\***\Desktop\***\***\src\HUD\Components\Scripts\Tr\TrDataLoader.as:221]
    at SharedUtils::Utils$/_AddToVirtualFileSystem()
    at SharedUtils.Missions::Mission/SaveMission()[C:\Users\***\Desktop\***\***\libs\SharedUtils\Missions\Mission.as:287]
    at LoadDialogue/SaveSelectedData()
    at LoadDialogue/OKClose()
    at TrLibrary_fla::btnOk_46/LeftClick()
    at TrLibrary_fla::_ButtonInstance_5/LeftClick()
```

**Console Output - With 2 magic traces in**

```
pathArr: 
pathArr: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
pathArr: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
pathArr: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
LastFP: [object Object]
```

**Update:**
To add to the annoyance, i added in 2 trace statements to the method that calls this block and magically all is as it should be. Removing both trace statements and it breaks again, but leave one in and remove the other and it works.

**Update 2/3:** 
Added more code before if statement as well as additional trace statements to methods before and after as well as the console outputs. Note, as this is Flash Builder i always perform a full "Clean Build" as I've been bitten before by FB's buggy ass partial builds.

**Update 4:**
As an array is what is being called and i recall reading something about how AS 3.0 handles arrays i decided to deep copy the array parameter in the call to the SaveMission method and removed the magic trace statements. It works for now (2 test runs) without the magic traces. I'd love to know why though?

`instance.trRoot.selMission.SaveMission(selFile,**pathArr**);` to `instance.trRoot.selMission.SaveMission(selFile,**Utils.DeepCopy(pathArr)**);` and works without traces?

Comment: Could you copy/paste the exact output of the compiler please?

Comment: show us the `Utils._AddToVirtualFileSystem` method, is that where the traces magically fixed it?

Comment: The compiler leaves no messages, warnings or errors. Added the console log for addl info.The magic traces that fix it come before the SaveMission method is called, added a truncated version of that class as it's around 488 lines long and the traces are during Init and just before the method call